# Not able to create JSF 2.2 project in Eclipse/RAD 9.5 without disabling library configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, websphere, rad

I am using IBM RAD 9.5.  I am not sure what version of Eclipse that corresponds to.  This version of RAD comes with WebSphere version 8.5.

When I try to create project:

```
New > Web Project > Java Server Faces
```

Under 'JSF Settings', if I pick version 2.2, it won't allow me to create the project unless I go under 'JSF Library' and select 'Disable Library Configuration' (Version 2.0 selects 'Default JSF Implementation', this option is not available when 2.2 is picked.)

When I do select 'Disable Library Configuration', I get the message

```
This facet requires JSF implementation library to be present on the project 
classpath.  By disabling library configuration, user takes on responsibility 
of configuring classpath appropriately via alternate means
```

What does this mean?  What else do I need to do to ensure my configurations are OK.

NB: My environment would not allow me to post screenshots. So I have described the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear WebSphere 8.5 contains only JSF 2.0 implementation.  In order to get the application work with JSF 2.2, the JSF 2.2 JARs would need to be included in the application classpath.